# Adding gdi+ reference to project in VS2010

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, gdi+

I'm trying to create a project with which I can manipulate TIFF files. (Mainly reorder, delete, insert images into multi-image TIFFs.)

My boss told me about gdi+ framework I could use to do this. I've downloaded the .exe and extracted the files in C:/Windows/system32 as well as my project's folder. When trying to make a reference in VS to this dll, I get:

> A reference to 'XXXXXX' could not be added. Please make sure that the
>   file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component.

I read online that I had to register the dll, I've tried doing this both with regsvr32 and regasm. Both give me the following error:

> RegAsm : error RA0000 : Failed to load
>   'C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.Windows.
>   GdiPlus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.0.6002.22509_x-ww_c7dad023\gdiplus.dll'
>   because it is  not a valid .NET assembly

can anyone help me? Thanks!

**Update:** I'm running a windows XP pc, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Gdiplus.dll is pre-installed on XP.  Hope you didn't mess up your machine too much.  Use the Bitmap class in .NET, GetFrameCount, SelectActiveFrame and SaveAdd lets you tinker with multi-image TIFFs.

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure you have a reference to `System.Drawing`.  It shouldn't be a separate download.

Answer (score 0):

This dll is a native windows dll, so it can't be referrenced directly.
You can only use assembly or COM dll in your project.
You have to define all of the methods and types, here is a little help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx

But you have to know all of the methods and signitures in the dll or simple find a .NET wrapper for that dll.